# LinearLayout with cells having different background? Possible?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a requirement where I need to have a LinearLayout and for each cell of this layout, I would have a different background to it.
This is the designer's example:

http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/1857/untilied.png

Is there any way I can achieve this only by XML, or should it be done at runtime? How can I get the cell count of the linear layout and work on this number?

Many thanks,
Felipe

Comment: What will you have in the LinearLayout? A `ListView`?

Comment: Those TextViews are added dynamically or already defined in the XML?

Comment: All will be added in the XML, but the value of one should change at runtime

Answer (score 1):

You can define a background for each TextView in XML. Just use the `android:background`

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:background="@color/blue" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:background="@color/red" />

</LinearLayout>
```

To change dinamically you can do something like this:

```
TextView txtView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
txtView1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
```

Comment: The problem is, for one cell, I will need three TextViews horizontally disposed in it. And, my background is not a color, but a drawable.

Comment: In my example i used a color but if you read the `setBackgroundResource` documentation you see that you can use a drawable. I am not understanding exactly what you want.

Comment: Imagine I have a parent linear layout (Orientation vertical). For each cell of this linear layout, I will have a child linear layout. This child only has one cell (orientation horizontal) and will have three text views.

Now, I need each cell of the parent LinearLayout to have a different drawable.

Makes sense?

Comment: so basically you want to set a drawable for each LinearLayout child, is that it?

Answer (score 1):

As you don't know the number of items to be added, you should add TextViews dynamically and not statically through XML . You should first take the height of the device screen and then you should add TextViews to the parent container based on this formaula:

> no of TextViews = (display height) / (height of one text view)

Now you just have to create TextViews dynamically and add them to the parent container  in a loop.

Here is a sample code for this:

```
public class DynamicActiviy extends Activity {

/*parent container*/
LinearLayout root;

/*colors*/
Integer[] colors = {R.color.red1,R.color.red2,R.color.red3,R.color.red4,R.color.red5,
        R.color.red6,R.color.red7,R.color.red8,R.color.red9,R.color.red10};

/*text view height*/
final int MAX_HEIGHT = 60;

/*display height*/
int displayHeight;

/*no of text views to be added*/
int noTextViews;

TextView text;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.backs);

    root = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.root);
    displayHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    noTextViews = displayHeight / MAX_HEIGHT;

    int size = colors.length;
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, MAX_HEIGHT);

    for(int i=0; i<noTextViews; i++)
    {
        text = new TextView(this);
        text.setBackgroundResource(colors[i%size]);
        text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        text.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
        text.setText(colors[i%size]+ "");
        root.addView(text,lp);
    }
}
```

}